# Varnish as a web server

Tags: varnish

I'm looking for a way to configure Varnish to handle HTTP request within Varnish.

More specifically, for specific paths(say under */foo/** ), I want Varnish to respond with 200 HTTP status code and empty(or fixed message) body, rather than forwarding requests to backend servers.

Comment: I think you could abuse `vcl_error` to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree to Michael's short response to abuse/use vcl_error for this purpose and like to show you what we meant in the example code below.

To abuse vcl_error I have used here error codes outside of the HTTP standard and implement a special treatment for this kind of errors.

Example in VCL_RECV:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  # respond HTTP 200 to /ping requests
  if (req.url ~ "^/ping") {
    error 700;
  }
  # return a 301 redirect
  if (req.url ~ "^/wrong-target") {
    error 751 "http://www.example.com/correct-target";
  }
}
```

Example in VCL_ERROR:

```
sub vcl_error {
  # send response "Pong" (HTTP 200)
  if (obj.status == 700) {
    set obj.status = 200;
    set obj.response = "OK";
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/plain";
    synthetic {"Pong"};
    return (deliver);
  }
  # send empty response (HTTP 204)
  if (obj.status == 701) {
    set obj.status = 204;
    set obj.response = "No Content";
    synthetic {""};
    return (deliver);
  }
  # redirect 301
  if (obj.status == 751) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 301;
    set obj.response = "Moved Permanently";
    return (deliver);
  }
  # redirect 302
  if (obj.status == 752) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 302;
    set obj.response = "Found";
    return (deliver);
  }
  # Fall through to default behavior for all other exceptions
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and also the official way (per Varnish docs) to handle this.  However, both your answer and the Varnish docs have an omission: if you don't set `obj.response` to something sane, then you'll get `HTTP/1.1 200 Unknown Error` or even `HTTP/1.1 200 http://www.example.com/correct-target` in your response!  Simple fix: `obj.response = "OK"` for `200`, or other appropriate code for the others.

Comment: @BMDan: Thank you for this important hint. I have updated the pasted code to set proper HTTP status messages.

Comment: Thanks @jens-bradler, this was exactly what I wanted, and I didn't know there's a HTTP status code as "204:No Content"!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but you very much *don't* want `return(deliver)` at the very bottom of your `vcl_error`!  If it doesn't satisfy any of the conditionals, you want it to fall through to the default behavior of constructing a "Guru Meditation" page (by not `return`ing at all).

Answer (score 3):

For future readers of this question, I ported @jens-bradler 's vcl to Varnish 4.
(Serverfault doesn't allow me to post multiple line code as comments, so I post here as another answer)

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/ping") {
        return (synth(700, "Ping"));
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^/wrong-target") {
        return (synth(751, "http://www.example.com/correct-target"));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    if (resp.status == 700) {
        set resp.status = 200;
        set resp.reason = "OK";
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/plain;";
        synthetic( {"Pong"} );
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (resp.status == 701) {
        set resp.status = 204;
        set resp.reason = "No Content";
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/plain;";
        synthetic( {""} );
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (resp.status == 751) {
        set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.reason = "Moved Permanently";
        return (deliver);
    }

    if (resp.status == 752) {
        set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
        set resp.status = 302;
        set resp.reason = "Found";
        return (deliver);
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Comment: You probably want to delete the `return(deliver);` from the bottom of `vcl_synth`, lest you fail to run this code from builtin.vcl (née default.vcl): https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl?rev=e5c7502defb50e8e0b5113b583c1a7e7a1365d1b#L132 .

Comment: @BMDan - perhaps you can type here what to write instead of "return (deliver);" Plus the URL you typed here is invalid.

Comment: @hB0 it looks like Varnish has moved their code.  https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/e1e7e764bd8c53900a204551c8123971b778e85f/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L117 appears to be a current link.